# Mongo write error: new file allocation failure

Tags: mongodb

I am encountering a Mongo write error (code 12520, message "new file allocation failure") when attempting to insert into a collection. I can insert into other collections in the same database without a problem and there is space on the disk. I have set the ulimits as recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings), and followed the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/a/626995). `cat /proc/<mongod_pid>/limits` shows that the higher limits have been applied. The issue first occurred with approx 7.5m documents, and after emptying the collection it has occurred again at 7653926 documents.

Does anyone know what the issue might be, or where to start looking?

Comment: Which [storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/storage-engines/) are  you using ? Are you running on 32bit machine ? what filesystems type are you using ? cheers.